# DispatcherTimer in a new thread

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, dispatchertimer

I'm developing a c# application. I need 2 threads; the main one, and another that is continuously looking for information through my database.
I want to use `Dispatcher Timer` as:

```
dispatcherBd.Tick += (s,e) => CallPoll (s,e);
dispatcherBd.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,100);
dispatcherBd.Start();
```

If i do this into my main thread, everything works perfectly, but if I do into a new thread. It doesn't work.

```
public Main(){
    threadDB = new Thread(InitDispatcher);
    threadDB.Start();
}

private void InitDispatcher(){
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherBd.Tick += (s,e) => CallPoll (s,e);
    dispatcherBd.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,100);
    dispatcherBd.Start();
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: use dispatcher.invoke on your timer's tick

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I mean that it is not executed every 100ms, just 1 time.

Comment: The Timespan signature you are using is 100 seconds, not 100 milliseconds. Your first example shouldn't tick every 100ms either. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: excuse me, i mean 100s

Comment: Is `dispatcherBd` a local variable or a field? Just a guess: if it's a local variable it might get garbage collected and hence the timer is destroyed.

Comment: private void InitDispatcher(){
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherBd = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherBd.Tick += (s,e) => CallPoll (s,e);
    dispatcherBd.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,100);
    dispatcherBd.Start();
}

Comment: @r.t.moreno11 that's what I mean, make `dispatcherBd` a **field** or your class instead of a local variable, so it won't get garbage collected.

Comment: DispatcherTimer needs a dispatcher, your new thread doesn't have one.  Use the right kind of timer class, either System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer gets the job done without you having to use a thread.  If "CallPoll" takes less than 20 msec then just use DispatcherTimer on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, you declare `dispatcherBd` as a **local** variable inside `InitDispatcher()`:

```
private void InitDispatcher()
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherBd = new DispatcherTimer();
    // ...
```

So `dispatcherBd` is only in scope inside `InitDispatcher` and will be availabe for garbage collection as soon as the method is left.
When it gets garbage collected and finalized, the timer event will no longer be raised.

So try changing `dispatcherBd` to a **field** instead:

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherBd;

private void InitDispatcher()
{
    dispatcherBd = new DispatcherTimer();
    // ...
```

---

But note that `DispatcherTimer` invokes its handler on the UI thread. So if `CallPoll` takes a lot of time, your UI will be blocked.
So you might want to start another thread from the timer's handler:

```
dispatcherBd.Tick += (s, e) => { Task.Run(() => CallPoll(s, e)) };
```

or use a `System.Threading.Timer` instead of a `DispatcherTimer`. That one runs the `Tick` event on a thread pool thread.

In both cases you need to get back to the UI thread when you want to display the results on your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about manual threading unless absolutely necessary. Use `Task.Run` as a way to schedule your (possible, continuous) job on another thread. Don't forget about `Dispatcher.Invoke` proxy if you need to update your UI from newly created (non-UI) thread.

In case things are getting too complicated, consider `Reactive Extensions`. There exists timer out of the box and many, many more.